# jquery valum plugin button change

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax-upload

I am using Valum file upload plugin in my website as well as jquery-ui theme excite-bike also. Now my problem is button, which valum plugin provided to upload a file.I want to use my button to call valum`s uploader . How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use the Valum Uploader with a `button` - you pass it a container and it creates the "button" for you - which again is actually a div with some styling... you can style the created `div` using the `qq-upload-button` class